# Matlab realtime updating of imagesc with a slider

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colormap

I have a 3D Matrix that I want to view graphically as a color map to display. If my 3D matrix is of the form (x,y,z), I want the color map to display the (y,z) 2D matrix, and I want to have an additional slider to adjust the (x) coordinate. I am implementing this with imagesc.

After looking through some examples, this is the code I wrote

```
ct = 1000;
sys = squeeze(T(ct,:,:)); 

f = figure;
h = imagesc(sys);

b = uicontrol('Parent',f,'Style','slider','Position',[81,54,419,23],...
          'value',ct, 'min',1, 'max',total_time);

b.Callback = @(es,ed) updateSystem(h,squeeze(T(es.Value,:,:)));
```

However, after running the code I get the following error.

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
>
> Error in filament_simulation>@(es,ed) updateSystem(h,squeeze(T(es.Value,:,:)))
>
> Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

This is probably because I don't understand 'updateSystem' so well, but I'm surprised to see that the error is due to an invalid index, where could that be?

I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for the slider to have a non-integer value. You will want to round it before using it as an index

```
updateSystem(h, squeeze(T(round(es.Value), :, :)))
```

Rather than trying to use `updateSystem`(a Control System Toolbox function), you can use the following as your callback to update the image data.

```
b.Callback = @(es, ed)set(h, 'CData', squeeze(T(round(es.Value), :, :)));
```

Comment: Ah I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks! However, another problem has come about, the error saying that 'updateSystem' cannot take a 'matlab.graphics.primitive.Image' as an input. Is there an alternative way to have a slider work with a color map?

Comment: @AlexKyriazis `updateSystem` isn't a MATLAB function so that's something that you must have written, no?

Comment: It's used as a callback, which is why it is probably not visible.

http://de.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/build-app-with-interactive-plot-updates.html

EDIT: Here is a direct link to the function
http://de.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/updatesystem.html

Comment: @AlexKyriazis That function is for working with the Control System Toolbox not general MATLAB GUI stuff. I can add an example of how to update the image.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could do that!! Thanks!